# Passing List into Apex - Want to insert individual attributes from list

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, list, parameters

I'm having some difficulty with lists and apex.

I have a list declared in my lightning component, please see below:

```
<aura:attribute name="AssetsList" type="List" default="[]"/>
```

I then set some attributes in the controller upon intialisation. I have two input fields in the component, the first 3 attributes apply to one input and the last 3 apply to the other. Please see this below:

```
component.set('v.AssetsList', {'TypeLabel': 'Asset Type', 'TypeValue': '','TypeId': 'AssetType1', 
                               'AmountLabel': 'Asset Amount', 'AmountValue': '', 'AmountId': 'AssetAmount1'});
```

I have a save button in the component and when it is clicked it will run a method in the controller where I pass the list to the apex as a parameter.

```
    var AssetList= cmp.get('v.AssetsList');
    var FactfindId = cmp.get('v.ffRecord.Id');
    var inputAssetListAction = cmp.get("c.inputAssetList");

    inputAssetListAction.setParams({
        "AssetList": AssetList,
        "FactfindId": FactfindId
    });

    inputAssetListAction.setCallback(this, function (response) {
        //store state of response
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log(state);
            if (response.getReturnValue() != null) {
                // if getting any error while update the records , then display a alert msg/
                alert('The following error has occurred. while updating record-->' + response.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.log('check it--> update successful');
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(inputAssetListAction);
```

Once this parameter is in the apex, I'm then trying to insert a record to a custom object. I currently have this code.

```
public static void inputAssetList(list<String> AssetList, string FactfindId) {

    FactfindMultiples__c[] Assets = new List<FactfindMultiples__c>();

    for(Integer i=1;i<AssetList.size();i++)
    {
        FactfindMultiples__c Asset = new FactfindMultiples__c(Name='Asset' + i, 
                                                              AssetType__c= AssetList[i].TypeValue);
        Assets.add(Asset);

    }
}
```

I'm going through the Asset List and trying to push it into a new record for my custom object. Once this is done, I'll then add to a list of the new custom object which I'll insert.

The issue I'm having is for when I'm setting the AssetType__c custom field, I don't want to push every attribute for each part of the array. I just want to use the TypeValue attribute that I set in the list upon initialisation.

I've tried syntax like AssetList[i].TypeValue but this returns errors.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thank you,

Owen

Comment: check attribute name which should be the same `AssetsType`, and are you getting `AssestList` in Apex? try with debug log

Answer (score 0):

The component you are initializing in js controller is v.AssetsType where the attribute name for the list is different "AssetsList". shouldn't these be same.
I think you just need to update attribute name to AssetsType.

```
<aura:attribute name="AssetsType" type="List" default="[]"/>
```

Comment: Apologies I've made this change and I'm still having the issue.

Comment: Console log the list in JavaScript controller before passing it to the apex controller and also debug log the `AssetsType` list in apex controller to see if you are getting list in apex or not

Comment: Hi, I've checked it in the controller and I'm getting an output in my console.

When I go to the controller and try and show it a system.debug I can't find anything in my logs.

Comment: Looks like its not getting passed to your apex controller. Data in `AssetsType` is more like a map. You can change `list<String> AssetList` input parameter to a map like this `Map<String, String> AssetList` and see if it logs something in apex debug logs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help so far, sorry but I am inexperienced with the use of maps. I am now getting simple static text outputs in my logs. I guess the next step would to try and print a value of the map into a log. Do you know how I'd do this?

Once again thanks for all the help.

Comment: If you have a map defined in apex class or you are passing it to your apex class method lets say you have a map `Map<String, String> AssetMap`. you can debug log whole map like this `system.debug(AssetMap)`. 

Map are basically key value pair there is a key and a value stored in map against that key like `Map<key,value>`. so if you know key you can debug value aginst that key like this `system.debug(AssetMap.get('key'))`. you can read more about maps from following [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm)

Comment: Hi,  

I've tried to do what you've suggested above.  

At the minute I'm using this line of code  `public static void inputAssetList(Map<String, String> AssetList)`.  

Then I'm doing this `system.debug('Map test: ' + AssetList);`  

Unfortunately it returns the following: "Map test: null"

Do you have any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? Sorry to bother you again.